# what is a single word or short phrase in English for "a nation within a State"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

A sovereign state (a 'country' in common language) consisting of 2 or more nations  (as in geographically defined, ethnic nationality) or even a sovereign state having 'at least one distinctive Nation within it', based on the example of Quebec [1], seems to be currently defined as a [multi-national state](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinational_state), but I couldn't find a single word or even short phrase for the reverse: "a nation within a state", although this exact longer phrase is in frequent use, as the following Google search will show:

[Google search for "nation within a state"](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=%22nation+within+a+state%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b&gfe_rd=cr&ei=e89lWa-DGIGEvATypZsw)

A few examples: Wales, Scotland, Brittany, Quebec (arguable), Ukraine when it was part of the former USSR (also applicable to all the other nations that once made up the USSR, later becoming independent states) and the [Navajo Nation.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navajo_Nation)

So what is a single word or short phrase meaning 'a nation within a state?'

Mandatory Example for SWR: Nation A is a __________ , which means that Nation A is a *nation within a state.*

Note: It is *not* enclave or exclave which terms instead deal with 2 or more entirely sovereign states.

Note 2: members are earnestly requested to please resist the temptation to engage in any political debate, and my question is concerned solely with the linguistic aspects of the matter.

---

[1] In 2006, the House of Commons of Canada voted in favor of Government Business No. 11, which states that the Québécois "form a nation within a united Canada".

Source: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinational_state under the heading 'modern multinational or multiethnic states' - Americas - Canada.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the word you really want is simply **nation**.

> A large aggregate of communities and individuals united by factors such as common descent, language, culture, history, or occupation of the same territory, so as to form a distinct people. Now also: such a people forming a political state; a political state

- *Oxford English Dictionary*

But the distinctions between *country*, *nation*, and *state* are quite complicated.  For instance, according to the [CIA World Factbook](https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/the-world-factbook/geos/us.html), The United States is considered a **country** comprised of multiple **states**.  This terminology dates back to the founding of the U.S., when there was disagreement between forming a [Confederation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confederation) or a [Federation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federalism), as was ultimately done by the [The Constitutional Convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constitutional_Convention_(United_States)).

On the other hand, [The United Kingdom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Kingdom) is considered a **sovereign state** that includes multiple **countries**: England, Scotland, Wales and Northern Ireland.

At the same time, The United Kingdom itself can be referred to as a *country*.

All of these terms are complicated by their multiple and overlapping definitions.  For instance, OED provides definition 4.a for *country*, implying that it is smaller than a nation or state, as with Wales or Scotland.

> 4. a. An area of land of defined extent characterized by its human occupants or boundaries; a district or administrative region, typically one smaller than a nation or state

A footnote on definition five delves into some of the confusion about the word *country*:

> With political changes, what were originally distinct countries have become regions or provinces of one country, **and vice versa**, but the tendency is to identify the term with the current political condition.

The question is complicated further by the complex definitions of *nation*.  While Quebec is quite arguably a nation within Canada, as well as a province by name, anti-separatists would probably take political umbrage with using the term *nation*.  That's because of that second part of the definition of "nation" provided at the top of this answer:

> Now also: such a people forming a political state; a political state.

This creates some political implications regarding terminology that make it hard to give a clear-cut answer that applies in all cases.  Still, I believe that the most accurate term to refer to a nation, whether it is among others in a state or not, would still be **nation**.  Perhaps there is a more precise terminology for nations that exist within a larger state; Other users will surely contribute to that question.

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive answer, @RaceYouAnytime: 'country' within a state seems being used interchangeably with 'nation' which is indeed the most basic term we can use, but the quest for a more defining word is in order to distinguish a nation-within-a-state from a nation-state where the nation is itself a sovereign state.

Answer (score 1):

The State is a political organization and structure formed by people. People typically will form groups called Nations since they share a common culture, history and ethnicity. Nations can be stateless, that is, a Nation does not necessarily have a defined or developed political structure such as the State. States on the other hand will contain at least one Nation. A Nation that forms a State is called Nation State. Also, a Nation can exist in many States.  Hence, a  Nation within   a State is still called Nation

Comment: Thanks for your excellent answer @Alex Sarmiento and for pointing out that a 'nation' can itself exist as part of multiple states: 'nation' is indeed the most basic term we can use, but the quest for a more defining word is in order to distinguish a nation-within-a-state or nation-within-multiple-states from a nation-state where the nation is itself a sovereign state.

Answer (score 1):

In a sociological perspective, another term would be **minority** if the nation in a state is relatively small.

> **Minority**: a small group within a community or country that is
>   different because of race, religion, language, etc.

Comment: I get your point, @Mustafa, and it is very relevant.  Please note I've specifically defined 'nation' with a geographical basis here (see question) as in, the geographical entity Wales, Scotland, Brittany, Quebec, the [Basque](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basque_Country_(greater_region)) nation, etc. If ethnic minorities either 'scattered all over the state' or 'far from their homeland' were taken as a 'nation' each, the USA would also be a multi-national state with around 150 significant ethnic minorities -- which many already suggest it actually is! I upvote your very interesting answer.